# Back4apps REST Login Not Working?

Tags: rest, parse-server, back4app

I tried both GET and POST way to login using Back4Apps parse server hosting, always got this:

```
{"code":101,"error":"Invalid username/password."}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I was using the wrong url.